# ReactJS render called twice with empty State

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to ReactJS and in one of my component render block the map is executed correctly and later it shows an error.

```
class CustomerList extends Component {
        constructor(props,context) {
            super(props, context);
            this.loadCustomersFromServer()
      }
        loadCustomersFromServer() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/customers',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: (data) => {
                    this.setState({results: data});
                },
                error: (xhr, status, err) => {
                    console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
                }
            });
        }
        componentDidUpdate(){
            console.log("componentDidUpdate")
        }
        componentWillUpdate(){
            console.log("componentWillUpdate")
        }
        render() {
        return (
            <div className="col-lg-12">
                <h1>Registered Clients</h1>
                <div className="table-responsive">
                    <table className="table table-bordered table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>#</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Address</th>
                                <th>Actions</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {
                             this.state.results.customers.map((customer, index) => {
                                return <Customer key={index+1} index={index+1} customer={customer}/>
                             })
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default CustomerList
```

In my browser all the table is rendered perfectly but in my console it shows an error saying

> Cannot read property 'results' of null at CustomerList.render (CustomerList.js:44)

at this line

> this.state.results.customers.map

Did I miss something that makes my map function to trigger twice with empty state??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So,

`this.state.results.customers.map` doesn't have the data you intented to add.

Try adding

```
constructor(props,context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.loadCustomersFromServer();
    this.state = {
      results:{customers:[]} ,
    };
}


loadCustomersFromServer() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/customers',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: (data) => {
            this.setState({results: data});
        },
        error: (xhr, status, err) => {
            console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

right below the constructor, and lemme know what comes.

Comment: inside constructor??

Comment: I'm getting an error while starting the server saying  Unexpected token (10:8) at state =

Comment: If I say this.setState({results:[]}) inside constructor and in componentDidMount if I call my api then I'm getting an empty table printed on my browser

Comment: @Pathfinder Ok, am a bit unfamiliar with the constructor one. Try it giving inside like this.

Comment: No, The issue is with the initial setting, where you need to tell that there's a state called `results` present. Everything else is correct. Check my updated ans.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137920/discussion-between-pathfinder-and-nevin-madhukar-k).

Comment: `results` is not a array in your `constructor ` !! i think this code must change to this `this.state = {
      results: [],
    };`

Comment: @AlirezaValizadeThat will never work. 
For `this.state.results.customers.` customers is the one expected as an array, not results.

Answer (score 1):

Change your class code to:

```
class CustomerList extends Component {
    state = {results:{customers:[]}};
    constructor(props,context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.loadCustomersFromServer()
    }
    .....
}
```

I am assuming your babel setup allows [class properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/). Otherwise move the state initialization code inside constructor, like @nevin-madhukar-k mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

you must check if results exist and unequal with `null` and then execute `map` function, try this:

```
   <div className="col-lg-12">
                <h1>Registered Clients</h1>
                <div className="table-responsive">
                    <table className="table table-bordered table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>#</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Address</th>
                                <th>Actions</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {
                             this.state.results && this.state.results.customers.map((customer, index) => {
                                return <Customer key={index+1} index={index+1} customer={customer}/>
                             })
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
```